# Google Maps InfoWindow with AJAX - "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<tg> has no method 'O'" error

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I'm trying to use the InfoWindow to display information I retrieve from an AJAX call. The infowindow isn't closing, and gives me this error as soon I click on the marker.

Here's a screenshot of the error in the Chrome Console.
[image: Error Messages in Chrome Console]

Here's my code:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function showBuildingInfo(map, building_code, marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      'url': '/maps/building/' + building_code,
      'dataType': 'html',
      'success': function(data) {
        infowindow.setContent(data);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    });
  });
}


function initialize() {
  var campusCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.6753005, -113.0732455);
  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.663559,-113.08003),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.677042,-113.066901)
  );

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: campusCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var newmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'static/images/campus.png',
      imageBounds);
  newmap.setMap(map);

  var ADLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.676189,-113.069555);

  var ADMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ADLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Bennion Administration Building",
  });

  showBuildingInfo(newmap, 'AD', ADMarker);
}
```

**EDIT**

I think my problem is a scoping issue. If I move the ajax call from within `showBuildingInfo` to the `addListener` function, like so, it works just fine.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
function initialize() {
  var campusCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.6753005, -113.0732455);
  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.663559,-113.08003),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.677042,-113.066901)
  );

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: campusCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var newmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'static/images/campus.png',
      imageBounds);
  newmap.setMap(map);

  var ADLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.676189,-113.069555);

  var ADMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ADLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Bennion Administration Building",
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(ADMarker, 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      'url': '/maps/building/' + 'AD',
      'dataType': 'html',
      'success': function(data) {
        infowindow.setContent(data);
        infowindow.open(map, ADMarker);
       }
    });
  });

}
```

I would like to remove the ajax call to a function so I don't have a lot code repetition. How can I do this?

**SOLUTION**

I think my mistake was using `newmap` (which isn't a `Map` object, but a `GroundOverlay` object) inside my AJAX `success` function. Passing in the `map` object seems to have fixed my problem.

To make things more clear, I renamed the `newmap` variable to `overlay`. I also moved the AJAX setup function definition into the initialize function so I wasn't passing as many variables in. Hopefully this code snippet can help someone else using AJAX for Google Maps Infowindow content.

```
function initialize() {
  var campusCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.6753005, -113.0732455);
  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.663559,-113.08003),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.677042,-113.066901)
  );

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: campusCenter,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var overlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'static/images/campus.png',
      imageBounds);
  overlay.setMap(map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var ADLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.676189,-113.069555);

  function setMarkerHandling(marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      $.ajax({
        'url': '/maps/building/' + marker.urlID,
        'dataType': 'text',
        'success': function(data) {
          infowindow.setContent(data);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  var ADMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ADLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Bennion Administration Building",
      urlID: "AD"
  });

  setMarkerHandling(ADMarker);
}
```

Comment: Where is `newmap` defined ?

Comment: That code has been added.

Comment: Are you running a minimized version of your code and showing us the source code?

Comment: There are other parts of the code, but I posted what I think are the relevant portions. Should I just post the entire script?

Comment: I just edited my question to include the entire script, as well as the rest of the working script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function setMarkerHandling(marker){

  //marker is trapped by closure in the function being defined as a handler

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    $.ajax({
      'url': '/maps/building/' + marker.urlID,
      'dataType': 'html',
      'success': function(data) {
        infowindow.setContent(data);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
       }
    });
  });

}
```

And then in the spot you show that works in your edited version:

```
  //add the context property you need to the marker (in this case urlID)

  var ADMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: ADLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "Bennion Administration Building",
      //you had a comma after title that shouldn've broke it by the way
      urlID: "AD"
  });

  //and now to set things up generically:
  setMarkerHandling(ADMarker);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a `target` when I print out the properties. The only properties that are printed out are `latLng
Sa 
pixel
ca 
stop`

Comment: Do you have a working version of the script that I could look at?

Comment: Well my assumption about googleMaps events may have been wrong. Checking docs.

Comment: @NathanJones Yeah, Google tends to be a little clueless when it comes to JavaScript (not that I'm complaining about V8 - thanks for that). You'll have to add that context info yourself to the marker. See the total answer rewrite and let me know how it goes.

Comment: To answer your earlier question. That script was working. It just revealed that they didn't put anything obviously useful in the event object for you so you have to add to markers manually and then re-use the same func to add that context info to your ajax calls dynamically. Also, note: I made a couple edits shortly after posting. I had an alert and a reference to ADMarker in the generic func, and a marker argument that would have broken the whole thing.

Comment: Ugh, okay. And I double-event-handled. Should just be setMarkerHandling func firing after Marker def.

Comment: I declared my map variable in the initialize function, so shouldn't that be passed into `setMarkerHandling` as well?

Comment: setMarkerHandling should be fired in whatever function/scope you defined the marker in with the marker as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing in valid data for the infoWindow content? From the docs:

```
content: This can be an HTML element, a plain-text string, or a string containing HTML.
```

I see the expected `data` dataType is `text`, but maybe double-check that it's correctly being handled.

Comment: My AJAX call is returning html, but when I tried using `html` dataType instead of `text`, I get the exact same behavior.